# Combining unknown number of objects with unknown number of input values

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I have a set of objects, and the function I want to implement receives a list of update values to update my objects with. The update values can be used to update at most one object, but can be a result on their own.

So, for example,

- my objects are: **[a, b, c]**.
- my update function is called with parameter *[d, e]*.

What I would like to have is all combinations of updates of my objects (a, b, c) with the parameter values, where order does not matter (as in, only one of [abce] and [eabc] need and should occur). Some possible results:

- [**a**; **b**; **c**]
- [**a** *e*; **b** *d*; **c**]
- [**a** *d*; **b**; **c** *e*]
- [**a**; **b**; **c** *e*; *d*]
- [**a**; **b**; **c**; *d*; *e*]
- ...

The simplest example is for both lists to be of size 1 (say, [a] and [d]):

- [**a** *d*]
- [**a**]
- [*d*]

Neither the number of objects nor the number of update values is known in advance.

How would I go about implementing this? Thanks!

---

The **background**, for anyone curious, is tracking of multiple targets using multiple-hypothesis tracking. My objects are tracks, and update values are sensor events. Each sensor event either updates a single existing track, spawns a new track or is regarded noise.

---

EDIT:
Based on Jurgen's answer below, I implemented it like this:

```
static LinkedList<String> update(List<String> trackLst, List<String> eventLst) {

    LinkedList<String> newTracks = new LinkedList<String>();

    for ( int e = 0; e < eventLst.size(); e++ )
    {
        String  evt = eventLst.get( e );

        for ( int i = 0; i < trackLst.size(); i++ )
        {
            String  trk = trackLst.get( i );

            if ( trk == null )  trk = new String("");

            trk = trk.concat( evt );
            newTracks.add(trk);
        }

        // No update
        newTracks.add( eventLst.get(e) );
    }

    return newTracks;
}
```

To expand a little on the **performance** question: In reality, one would test each association for usefulness in the form of a performance or coherence measure before including it in the final list of hypotheses. It is still a large number, but exhausting tests are necessary when objects often overlap and the sensor resolution is low, so that we can delay the association until later when more meaningful data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```
List<Tracks>  trackLst = ....;
List<SensorEvent>  eventLst = ....;

// Make the 2 lists equal in length
while ( trackLst.size() > eventLst.size() )  eventLst.add( null );
while ( eventLst.size() > trackLst.size() )  trackLst.add( null );

for ( int e = 0; e < eventLst.size(); e++ )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < trackLst.size(); i++ )
    {
        SensorEvent  evt = eventLst.get( i );

        if ( evt != null )
        {
            Track  trk = trackLst.get( i );

            if ( trk == null )  trk = new Track();

            trk.update( evt );
        }
    }

    eventLst.add( eventLst.remove(0) );
}
```

Comment: This creates a single random set of track-update associations. What I am looking for is all possible associations.

Comment: @seb Added outer for loop to shift / rotate SensorEvents to get all combinations - I think ?

Comment: That's it. Only it should be eventLst.get(e) (I tried to change it, but apparently that's not enough changes for an edit). See also my edit above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using recursion. Each parameter has n+1 options to choose from. Either it can get associated with any of the n objects, or it can stay on its own.

Hence if the initial 'remaining list objects' is the list of objects [a, b, c, ...],and the remaining list of parameters is [d, e, ...],

A possible pseudo-code:

```
void recur( list<pair> soFar, list remainingObjects, list remainingParam ) {
  if ( remainingParam is empty ) {
    add remainingObjects to soFar;
    print soFar;
    return;
  }

  for parameter in remainingParam: {
    for object in remainingObject: {
      (remove object and parameter from remaining lists and add pair to soFar)
      recur(...);
    }

    (remove only parameter from remainingParam list and add it to soFar as sole object)
    recur(...);
  }

}
```

Comment: From what I can gather from your code, this too would create one possible association of input values to objects. What I am looking for is a complete collection of all possible associations. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: n+2 options actually as it can be noise as well. And I'm afraid, that recursion is a bad idea on such an algorithm. It will slow it even further and you risk a stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

When I got your background right, you are missing out, that each of the input events could be an update to any other input event.

Furthermore I assume, that each input object can be an update to atmost one existing object. So listing all options will be an performance problem. Any algorithm can break, when it found a match.

So break the problem down to a single input event, that is either matched as update or creates a new track. Be aware, that in this case, depending on the matching logic, the input order does matter!

To answer your question though:

You have N tracks and M inputs. Then each input can belong to N + 1 (noise) + 1 (empty track) options. Thus you have `(n+2)^m` different ways to distribute inputs on options.

With M and N in order of 10 and 1000 this is already a performance nightmare with `O(N^M)`

With the assumption, that all events are co-located and may belong all to one or are noise, the problem is reduced to `O(N*2^M)`

Comment: "each of the input events could be an update to any other input event." I don't think so. The function would be called with the results of one scan, which contains sensor data from a single moment in time. Also, I cannot perform this for each input independently, as each combination of ALL input values forms a new hypothesis.

Comment: If this is the case, how can they then be updates to multiple tracks? Are they coming from different located sensors? In this case they cannot be updates to the same track, otherwise they belong to one track (or are noise)

Comment: each update consists of data from multiple sensors, which may overlap.